# Return top 10 words from 2000gb of data with memory constraints

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

> I have 2000GB of data of strings and my PC has 2GB of space. I want to return top 10 words with the highest frequency across the data.

I was asked this in a technical interview. I tried solving it using HashMap, Priority Queue but the interviewer was not satisfied because of the worst case scenario that every word occurs only once.

Comment: What's the criterion for optimization? Speed, space, or something else?

Comment: Histogram algorithm?

Comment: Similar: [most frequent 100 numbers out of 4,000,000,000](/q/64870685/3789665)

Comment: @Sirko The interviewer didn't asked me to do any of these they just asked for a working solution

Comment: Even more similar: [Given a file, find the ten most frequently occurring words as efficiently as possible](/q/4495241), a comment mentioning [Count sketch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_sketch).

Answer (score 0):

One good way (not necessarily the fastest way) to solve this is:

1. Go through the text, extracting each word, and writing it to a file. The file contains one word per line.
2. Sort that output file. You now have a file, one word per line, where all the instances of a single word are grouped together.
3. Create min heap of size 10 that is initially empty.
4. Read the file sequentially, counting the instances of each word. When words change (i.e. you counted 6 instances of "apple" and the next word is "aardvark"):

   If the heap has fewer than 10 words in it, insert the word and its count into the heap.

   If the heap has 10 words in it and the count of the current word is greater than the count of the word at the root of the heap (the lowest count currently in the heap), then remove the smallest item from the heap and insert your word.

In the case of all words occurring the same number of times, this will do 10 insertions into the heap.

Linux and other Unix-like systems have the `sort` utility, which I think will work on multi-terabyte files. I know I've sorted files that were hundreds of gigabytes in size. Whether the Windows SORT command will work with multi-terabyte files is an open question. But with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, it's rather a moot point: just install WSL and use the Linux `sort`.

If you're unable to sort a multi-terabyte file, things get a little more complicated. Basically, you split the file up into sortable-sized chunks, sort them, and then merge the sorted files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in place is the obvious idea. Then scan to count the spans of identical strings, tracking the top ten string/count pairs as you go.

But a simple way around the memory constraint is to scan the strings N times e.g. from input files, where N is small, hopefully 2. Use a high quality hash function to map them to integers in, say, 0..2^64-1. Split this space N ways and ignore anything not in the k'th split while making the k'th pass.

Now memory is only (about) 1/N full of strings. In the rest of the space, use your favorite data structure to find the top 10 in each split along with their frequencies.

Finally, merge the N results and take the top 10 from them.

It might seem crazy to read the data from a file two or more times. But modern architectures are highly optimized for sequential streams. It might not be so crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have another *2000*Gb of disk space.

Consider hash function *h* with *2000* output values. Scan original data, split it into *2000* files by value of *h*.

Process each file with hash map counting string frequencies. If hash map fits memory delete the file and update global top ten. If it does not apply the same procedure recursively to the file. For file of size *X*Gb, consider another hash function *g* with *2X/2* values. First *2* is a safety factor, second *2* is amount of memory. Split the file with hash function *g* values recursively. Remove the file to save disk space.

Apply splits until you have all data split into files fit memory. Due to nature of split no two files contain the same string. After processing all files you've got global top ten.

**P.S.** With high probability each file will fit memory after first scan.

Comment: From the histogram/ *hash map* after processing a single file, how much information do you need and how do you keep it "between files"?

Comment: @greybeard, top ten strings with counts. "no two files contain the same string". So after processing one file you now global counts for all strings you've seen in the file.

Comment: (Would upvote this if a) the question didn't look a duplicate and this answer didn't look the same as [Gene's](/a/78045176/3789665). Would upvote Genes if not a) and I thought Gene's as clear as yours.)

Comment: @greybeard, you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: @greybeard, my point is to avoid sorting. Sorting requires NlogN. Hash split requires N. Huge difference for 2000Gb. I'm using additional drive space to avoid multiple passes of source file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are not in a rush, you could do the following.

- 1 Copy the data to storage (not RAM) and operate on the copy (as it will be mutated).
- 2 Maintain a hashmap, initially empty, but quickly having 10 keys. The keys are the 10 words with highest frequency found so far and the values are the frequencies.
- 3 Select the first word `w` in the first (remaining) string. Add it to the hashmap with a value of 1 and delete the word from the string. Delete the string if it is then empty.
- 4 Go through all words of all strings. Whenever `w` is found in a given string increment it's count in the hashmap, remove the word from that string and delete that string if it is then empty.
- 5 Once the hashmap contains 11 keys remove the key with the smallest value, leaving the 10 keys (words) having the highest frequencies found so far.
- 6 Repeat from Step 3 until no strings remain.

Comment: (The problem is mapping deletion in step 5: imagine top *2* and words a, b, c, a, e, f, a, b, c, a, e, f….)

Comment: Right - wasn't ready to assume anyone had *that* much time.

Comment: If you have enough space to copy the data, just sort it.

Comment: @greybeard, though ugly, instead of deleting words you could replace one of its characters with a character not permitted in text and do that in place. From a practical point of view I wouldn't expect most texts to have more than a couple of thousand unique words. When the OP reported that the interviewer was concerned about the case where every word in 2000GB of text appeared only once I was wondering what language they had in mind.

Comment: @greybeard, suppose words are `a, b, c, a, e, f, a, b, c, a, e, c`. For top 2, initially hashmap is `{ a:4 }`, leaving `b, c, e, f, b, c, e, c`, then `{ a:4, b:2 }`, leaving `c, e, f, c, e, c`, then `{ a:4, b:2, c:3 }`, leaving `e, f, e`, then drop key `:b`, as of the three keys it has the lowest frequency, leaving, `{ a:4, c:3 }`, and so on.